# PostgreSQL - how do I know which function uses a type?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a type defined in my server:

```
CREATE TYPE typ_gbom AS
(
   ab citext,
   id   integer,
   name citext,
   user citext,
   comment citext
);
ALTER TYPE typ_gbom 
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

I want to find all functions that return this type.

Meaning all function that has:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a()
  RETURNS setof typ_gbom AS
```

or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a()
  RETURNS typ_gbom AS
```

I tried:

```
select * from pg_proc where prosrc ilike '%typ_gbom%'
```

But this is not working, this is looking only in the function code itself and not in it's structure.

How can I find if this type is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pg_depend` for this:

```
select n.nspname as function_schema, p.proname as function_name
from pg_proc p 
  join pg_namespace n on n.oid = p.pronamespace 
  join pg_depend d on d.objid = p.oid and d.classid = 'pg_proc'::regclass 
  join pg_type typ on typ.oid = d.refobjid 
  join pg_namespace ts on ts.oid = typ.typnamespace 
where ts.nspname = 'public' --<< change to your schema name 
  and typ.typname = 'typ_gbom'
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few functions that return function metadata. we can use them to extract the desired info

```
SELECT 
  p.proname as func_name,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) as result_type,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as argument_types,
 CASE
  WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
  WHEN p.proiswindow THEN 'window'
  WHEN p.prorettype = 'pg_catalog.trigger'::pg_catalog.regtype THEN 'trigger'
  ELSE 'normal'
 END as func_type
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_function_is_visible(p.oid)
  AND pg_catalog.pg_get_function_result(p.oid) IN ('typ_gbom', 'SETOF typ_gbom')
```

Comment: That would only return functions the _return_ that type. But would not include functions that have that type as an argument.

Comment: but that's what the op stated he wants: `I want to find all functions that return this type.`